# creating a simple electrical circuit using Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a beginner to three.Js library.How can i implement/create a circuit having batteries,bulbs,ammeter,switches using Three.js with simple features like glowing of a bulb when circuit is closed,toggling of existing state(open/closed) of button when clicked ,i tried to search it over the internet but didn't get any useful information regarding this.Can anyone attach some links or provide some information regarding this?

Comment: It feels like you haven't really thought about what you're asking. What have you tried so far? Why are you starting with creating a simulation of an electrical circuit?

Comment: Three.js is just a 3d engine you should implement electrical analysis code too

Comment: I am a beginner as i mentioned.I want to learn this cool library.So I took it as my project.So how I can proceed with it to create a simple circuit? @evolutionxbox

Comment: "create a simple circuit" what you do mean? Remember, ThreeJS is a 3d modelling library, it has no concept of circuitry. Unless you use another library, you'll need build all of it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was really bored )

Used stuff:
`THREE.CylinderGeometry()`, `THREE.SphereGeometry()`, `THREE.Shape()`, `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()`, `THREE.LineBasicMaterial()`, `THREE.Mesh()`, `THREE.Line()`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/nr3n6kbj/)

[image: circuit_onoff]

Comment: Thanks For your help !!! It really helped me to understand ThreeJs concepts thoroughly @prisoner849

Answer (score 0):

You can tried at
https://kazuhikoarase.github.io/simcirjs/
I hope will be useful for you...success!